# Resharper Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, resharper

Recently after upgrading to `Resharper 8.1`, i am facing a very strange bug which causes visual studio to remove (or combine 2 consecutive lines) every time i hit the debug start button. I knew that this is caused by `Resharper` because i tried to disable it and the problem just disappeared. So i immediately reset all settings of `Resharper` with no luck!.

Example:

```
UpdateData1();
UpdateData2();
```

Becomes

```
UpdateData1();UpdateData2();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the [exact problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461447/resharper-compile-time-autoformat-incorrectly-changes-code) I use VS2013, ReSharper 10.0.2 and DevExpress Components.

Solution is emptying the licences.licx file. I use this prebuilt script on VS0213:

```
break>$(ProjectDir)\Properties\licenses.licx
```

Comment: After a while I realized that also. I couldn't make it work. Unfortunately I've disabled ReSharper. I suspect it depends on DevEx Patch. @vcRobe do you use DevEx patch?

Comment: Yes, I'm using DevEx patch. I'm testing DevExpress but one month is not enough to do all required tests. And I also realized that the issue appear after installing DevEx